# django orm filter and exclude by related date field

Tags: django, django-models, orm

models.py

```
class Model(models.Model):
    ...


class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, related_name="related_model")
    date = models.DateField()
```

I want to filter objects realted by a `DateField` by month and year.

- first I do `Model.objects.all()` and I see 3 instances
- second I filter like this: `Model.objects.filter(related_model__date__month=6, related_model__date__year=2021)` the result is just 1 instance out of 3
- third and last, I filter like this `Model.objects.exclude(related_model__date__month=6, related_model__date__year=2021)` and the result is empty, I was so sure that the result will be the opposite to the second query, like 2 out of 3 instances.

any explanation?

thanks.

---

Answer from documentation:

> Nota
>
> The behavior of filter() for queries that span multi-value relationships, as described above, is not implemented equivalently for exclude(). Instead, the conditions in a single exclude() call will not necessarily refer to the same item.
>
> For example, the following query would exclude blogs that contain both entries with «Lennon» in the headline and entries published in 2008:
>
> Blog.objects.exclude(
> entry__headline__contains='Lennon',
> entry__pub_date__year=2008,
> )

> However, unlike the behavior when using filter(), this will not limit blogs based on entries that satisfy both conditions. In order to do that, i.e. to select all blogs that do not contain entries published with «Lennon» that were published in 2008, you need to make two queries:
>
> Blog.objects.exclude(
> entry__in=Entry.objects.filter(
> headline__contains='Lennon',
> pub_date__year=2008,
> ),
> )

Comment: What type of relation do you have in between

Comment: @iklinac it is a foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple `RelatedModel` instances for same `Model` where one of them could have `month=6` and another one `year=2021`. Exclude will also eliminate these

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) you will have to filter exactly instances with both conditions

```
Model.objects.exclude(
    related_model__in=RelatedModel.objects.filter(
        related_model__date__month=6,
        related_model__date__year=2021,
    ),
)
```